# Fuel pump and or fuel pump regulator module on 2006 Honda CRV 2.4 l

Tags: honda, crv, fuel-pressure-regulator

Okay so I'm working on this car and it hasn't been cranked or started and she said over a year approximately. When I tried to start it for the first time it cranked, but no start. Second time crank, no start. I figured the problem was the fuel pump, it must have burnt out because I couldn't hear it powering on anymore. After further inspection I came to the conclusion that it must have picked up some trash because when I took the pump out the gas was like a brownish red and the fuel pump was literally rusted all the way around. So I immediately ordered a new pump off Amazon cleaned up the housing and once the pump arrived two days later I replaced. Meanwhile during the wait I dropped the gas tank, drained all the bad gas out of it and washed it with soap and water and rinsed it out thoroughly and hand dried out then let it set overnight. Gas tank back on the next day and put the new fuel pump in the housing Saturday in their properly tightened down the cap put the nozzle on and plugged it in. When I went to start it I heard the pump power on so I primed it a couple times by turning the key forward and back twice then back again the third time and start. Started cranking just like last time but again no start. What else could I be doing with because there's no fuel running out of the housing into the lines?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If the fuel in the tank is as bad as you're saying, you can bet the fuel going forward from the tank is that bad.

Your next step is to disconnect the fuel line at the pump end, then from the front end (fuel rail or wherever you can disconnect it) and blow out what you can using compressed air. If you find it plugged, there may be a fuel filter in between that needs to be replaced. Once the line is cleaned and flowing (at least blowing air through), you need to pull the injectors and clean them. You can do that using an ultrasonic cleaner with mild detergent/cleaner. Once cleaned, put it all back together with fresh gas (I'm assuming you're good on the gas already). At that point, it should be good to go.